# Express js Router is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I am facing hard time with express js Routes. I have a user routes file, that I am requiring in app.js (main file). But it always gives Cannot GET /auth/register.

My user route is as follows:

```
const express = require('express');
const router  = express.Router();

router.get('register', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Hello');
    res.send('Register');
});
module.exports = router;
```

And my app file is as follows:

```
const express    = require('express');
const path       = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors       = require('cors');
const passport   = require('passport');
const mongoose   = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

const config     = require('./config/app');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/users');

//connecting with mongo DB
mongoose.connect(config.database);

// On successful connection
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
   console.log('Connected');
});

// On Error while connecting
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});

// Port of express server
const PORT = config.port;

// Adding cors middleware
app.use(cors());

// Adding Body Parser Middle ware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Adding user Routes

app.use('/auth', userRoutes);

// Start the express server
app.listen(PORT, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Server is Running on port " + PORT);
});
```

Comment: it's "/register" not "register"

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the symbol '/' in your user route. Try this:

```
router.get('/register', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Hello');
  res.send('Register');
});
```